# How to send android project with AndEngine libraries to another person

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine, file-transfer

I'm making a small android game for someone usign the AndEngine library and am stumped on how to easily send them the project without requiring them to do any configuration, just download the project import it into eclipse and run it.

AndEngine is a library based engine, to use it in your project you just add the actual source projects to your build path and reference them that way, so I need a way to send my project + the AndEngine source to them in such away that they can just run it without having to configure anything. I tried just putting all the projects(the game + the andengine library projects) in one workspace and sending the whole workspace but the projects are linked using the absolute path, instead of a path relative to my project, so it doesnt work on a different computer with different folders and everything.

How would you recommend I go about doing this? We will both be using eclipse.

This is the first time I've ever had to do anything like this and I have no idea where to begin, I really need help fast and I appreciate any responses I get, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does require some cinfiguration, I recommend using version control such as GIT to manage this. 
Bitbucket [has free private repositories (free for small teams, cheap for larger)](https://bitbucket.org/)
Github is also very popular.

Then you can simply send the git paths for the andengine library on github and the project in your repository and eclipse will do the rest.

To do this:

- Goto FILE>IMPORT>
- If you have the git plugin installed you will see a "GIT" folder option. Select "Projects from Git"
- Select "URL" from the repository source.
- Then paste in the repository path from bitbucket/github and finish the wizard.

When getting the URL from bitbucket, be sure to select the "HTTPS" option instead of "SSH" unless you want to set up RSA keys. And since you're looking for simple, you don't.

Also, if you are not both using it, I recommend tryign the android-specific build of eclipse google released called ADT - it has the eclipse git plugin integrated and other handy android tools and require a minimum of change.

One last thing: since you'll probably be sending files more than one, git also makes life easy because you just do a commit to the repository and the other person can grab the new updated files from the same source again.

Comment: this sounds great, I was considering doing something like this. I'm going to ask the person if they'd be ok with grabbing the code from git. In the meantime I'm still open to any other advice anyone may have, just incase he doesn't want to do the whole git thing.

Comment: I'm trying to upload to git but I can only load one project, the libraries im using with my project get added as 'modules' and when someone downloads the source they don't get the libraries

Comment: That's right. You will need a repository for each library. I don't think there is a push-one-button solution. But git is probably the lowest resistance. Unless you actually merge in the code from your library into your project, which is not usually the best path.